# Get Row Count in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have built a report using Report Builder 3.0 (that uses SQL Server 2008 R2). Now i wish to now how many records are being fetched from database to the report?

This is possible either by count function in SSRS or by using RANK/ROW_NUMBER function in SQL Query and assigning that as field to the report (RANK/ROW_NUMBER would give us rank to each row and navigating to last page in report would help me getting the total row count).

I tried count function but that counts on some field in the report. For instance  = `Count(Field!FieldName.value, "DataSetName")` Problem in this approach: "FieldName" is not unique in the report and hence the counts get repetitive

Second option: Added Rank/Row_Number but they too use the same kind of fieldName and hence here too the counts get duplicated.

Main Problem: There is no field in my query that is unique (and hence i tried ROW_NUMBER())

How can i find the total row count or rank (for each row) in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the [`CountRows` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). For example

```
=CountRows("MyDataset")
```

will give you the number of rows in *MyDataSet*.

Comment: It is simple to get row count. Just use of ROW_NUMBER in SQL Query would fulfill the aim

Comment: Also, if you're using FetchXML (i.e. for Dynamics) you won't be able to execute SQL functions.

Answer (score 6):

As someone else mentioned above, I couldn't get `CountRows("DatasetName")` to work in the header until I wrapped it thusly:`CSTR(CountRows("DatasetName"))`.

Comment: @Brian - thanks for marking the code for me, much more legible. I'll have to remember that!

Answer (score 1):

In the Tablix control's properties, there's a property name called **NoRowsMessage** put your message here when no row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

you can't put aggregation values into the detail wihtout grouping.
Solution is below:
`=Count(Fields!rn.Value)`

I use it inside the column/header row.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.  First create a data column with the value always set to 1.  This will provide a value of one for each row of data.

**Query Column**

```
, 1 AS Unit
```

Use the "RunningValue" function into your report as shown below.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Unit.Value,Sum,"DataSet")
```

This will also work as a 'running sum' if that's something you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used rowcount to get the index count per row in the grid